# modify a regex with another regex from code

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, escaping

I have a string '*out*' which I need to change for another string '*into*', in a text called '*text*'.

```
out = 'hello $ world'
into = '###'
text = 'this hello \n$ world text'
```

And I also want to know if there was any change.

As I see it, I should first, escape '*out'* text (to allow chars like '$' to be modified). Then, I should replace all ur'\s+' with '\s+', and this resulting string should contain the regex to be replaced with '###'.

To sum up: I have text like this:

```
text = 'this hello \n$ world text'
```

And I want this as a result:

```
result: 'this ### text'
```

I tried this:

```
re.sub(re.sub(ur'\s+', '\s+', re.escape(out)), into, text)
```

and get this as a result:

```
'this hello \n$ world text'
```

And also this:

```
re.sub(re.sub(ur'\s+', ur'\s+', re.escape(out)), into, text)
```

with the same result.

I think there are some problems with '\' char, but it's a bit confusing, how can I fix it? I'm running python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the main problem looks here that `re.escape(..)` **escapes whitespace** as well. Indeed:

```
>>> re.escape('hello $ world')
'hello\\ \\$\\ world'
```

It is however easy to alter that by substitute `r'\ '` by `r'\s+'`:

```
re.sub(r'\\\s+',r'\s+',re.escape(out))
```

Or the fill code:

```
>>> re.sub(re.sub(ur'\\\s+', ur'\s+', re.escape(out)), into, text)
'this ### text'
```

You can furthermore improve efficiency a bit of the resulting regex by replacing `r\(\\\s+)+'` instead, since two spaces in the original string now map to the same 'r'\s+'':

```
>>> re.sub(re.sub(ur'(\\\s+)+', ur'\s+', re.escape(out)), into, text)
'this ### text'
```

You can detect whether there is change by simply comparing the old `text` with the new one`. For instance:

```
new_text = re.sub(re.sub(ur'(\\\s+)+', ur'\s+', re.escape(out)), into, text)
change = text != new_text # change is a bool that is True if there is change
```

Comment: It worked! I have also read about re.subn which returns the number of changes. I forget saying this in my question, but this answer is correct.